# How to select text inside input element without JS/JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to generate an HTML element of input text and make the text inside it selected.

```
<body>
  <input type="text" value="Hello">
</body>

<script>
  $('input').select();
</script>
```

My question is how can I mark the text inside the input without JS, I mean that I'm looking for HTML attribute that can be placed inside 'input' HTML tag. Do you know something that can help?

**Edit:** 
Is there any way to do the operation of select(), but in Vanilla JS (without JQuery)?

Comment: use data attribute

Comment: data-text = "print information here".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a specific input to be focused directly
use

**note only 1 element can be fouced at a time and usually the first element is focused**
does not work on IE9 and below

```
 <input type="text" value="Hello" autofocus >
```

if your just looking for the styling i suggest CSS

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the **Data Attribute** to embed custom data.

**have a look** : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

- The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the
  page or application.
- The data-* attributes gives us the ability to embed custom data
  attributes on all HTML elements.

You Can use **Data-text** attribute with Java Script as well. 
Here is the Guide:

http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/